# How to access an Eloquent relationship using an associative array key

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Say I have Listing model with one-to-many relationship with an Attribute model:

```
class Listing extends Eloquent {
    public function attrs() {
        return $this->hasMany('Attribute');
    }
}

class Attribute extends Eloquent {
    public function listing() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Listing');
    }
}
```

Attributes have a code and a value.  When I'm handling the Listing, I want to be able to grab a specific attribute using an attribute's code, something like this:

```
$val = Listing::find($id)->attrs[$code]->value;
```

The above line obviously doesn't work.  There are a number of ways to solve this (eg. maintain an internal associative array of attributes indexed by code and fill it in the attrs() method; provide a getter function and just brute force search through the attrs array) but I wonder if there is an elegant way of doing this using something built in to Laravel.

Any ideas better than the ones I suggest above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `first()` method with closure on a Laravel collection:

```
$val = Listing::find($id)->attrs->first(function($model) use ($code){
   return $model->code == $code;
})->value;
```

However be aware that `first()` will return `null` if no model matches and you would get an exception (because you can't access `->value` of a non-object)

To avoid that wrap it in an if:

```
$attribute = Listing::find($id)->attrs->first(function($model) use ($code){
   return $model->code == $code;
});
$val = $attribute ? $attribute->value : 'default';
```

---

Alternatively you could filter the relation, which I think is more elegant:

```
$attribute = Listing::find($id)->attrs()->where('code', $code)->first();
$val = $attribute ? $attribute->value : 'default';
```

Comment: Ok, and is there a similar solution where the attrs relationship is eager loaded?  I should have mentioned that in my original question...

Comment: If they are eager loaded, use `first()` with the filtering closure

Comment: Right.  If I'm not mistaken, though, that basically amounts to my second solution of using a custom getter on the model with a brute-force search through the attrs array.  But you did answer the question of doing it in a Laravel-y way, thanks.

Comment: Yes. Well I wouldn't say brute force. It just loops through the array until a code matches. I wouldn't consider that too bad...